# i am trying to implemet split in c , i doesnt know why the my code get crashed when he do strcat

Tags: c, split, malloc, realloc, strcat

> ```
>     i am trying to implemet split in c , i doesnt know why the my code get crashed when he do strcat
> ```

```
  char** split(const char* str, char delimiter)
    {
        int index=0;
        int size=num_items(str,delimiter);
        char split[size+1];
```

// cell represent the cell in the array to return

```
        char* cell=(char*)malloc(1);
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if(str[i]!=delimiter)
            {
```

Increases the size of the cell before adding to it the next char every unsinged char is 8bits

```
            cell=realloc(cell,sizeof(cell)+8);
  
    ***the program get crashed after the strcat***
 
                strcat(cell,(unsigned const char*)str[i]); 
            }else{
                split[index]= (char) cell;
                free(cell);
                char* cell=(char*)malloc(0);
            }
        }
        return split;
    }
```

*** after writting again, i have the same problem with strcat, can somone explain to me my mistakes?***

```
char** split(const char* str, char delimiter)
{
    int ch=0;
    int word=0;
    const char * zero="\0";
    unsigned int size=num_items(str,delimiter);
    //char* cell=calloc(1,sizeof(char));
    char** split= calloc(size+1,sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) //i=colum
    {
        if(ch==0)
        {   //strcat(split[word],zero);
            memset(split[word],'\0',1);
            ch++;
        }
        if(str[i]!=delimiter)
        {
            strcat(split[word],&str[i]);
            ch++;
        }else{
            ch=0;
            word++;
        }
    }
    return split;
}
```

Comment: In general `T foo() { char s[N]; return s; }` is an error.  You cannot return the address of a local variable.  If you want to return an array, you will need to allocate space for `split` on the heap.

Comment: `sizeof(cell)` is constant (platform dependent), and is unrelated to the length of the string.  It is the size of a char pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating dynamically an uninitialized extent of memory

```
cell=realloc(cell,sizeof(cell)+8);
```

using the magic expression `sizeof(cell)+8` (that does not make a sense).

So as the extent of memory does not contain a string you may not use the function `strcat` like

```
strcat(cell,(unsigned const char*)str[i]);
```

Apart from this the function in any case does not make a sense and has undefined behavior. For example the array `split` is a local array of the function with automatic storage duration

```
char split[size+1];
```

In this return statement

```
return split;
```

the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`. However the function return type is `char **`.

```
char** split(const char* str, char delimiter)
^^^^^^
```

That is the type of the returned expression and the return type of the function are not compatible. Moreover the local array `split` will not be alive after exiting the function. So in any case the returned pointer will be invalid.

Or this statement

```
split[index]= (char) cell;
```

does not make a sense.

You need to rewrite the function anew.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are reallocating unallocated memory.
2. You are trying to catenate string to the uninitialized buffer. You need to 'memset()' this buffer or set '\0' character to the first element of this buffer after allocation.
3. You are trying to split a string into a string array, but you do not have information on how many tokens are written in the array after splitting. This will be also a problem when you need an iteration of this array. You can either write NULL in the last array element or pass the third pointer argument to the split function where you will be able to save array length.

P.S. there is an already made implementation of split and you can check this out or use it as a snippet.

This is the project: [libxutils](https://github.com/kala13x/libxutils). Check `xstrsplit()` function in `src/xstr.c` file.

The example code is looking something like that:

```
const char *pMyString = "this:is:test:strig";

xarray_t *pTokens = xstrsplit(myString, ":");
size_t i, nUsed = XArray_Used(pTokens);

for (i = 0; i < nUsed; i++)
{
    char *pTok = (char *)XArray_GetData(pTokens, i);
    printf("token: %s, order id: %zu\n", pTok, i);
}

XArray_Destroy(pTokens);
```